# Name of phobia of compromised account security

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

What would, if any, be the name of the phobia of a person who lives in constant fear of others breaking into their accounts / misusing their personal information? I've found some slightly related phobias such as "nomophobia", but none of them are quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: *"who lives in constant fear"* Are you sure you're looking for a phobia and not just a plain old paranoia?

Comment: It could be a subset of technophobia...

Comment: Could also be an extrapolation of *kleptophobia* - especially if money is involved. But identity theft is best covered by the general term *technophobia*.

Comment: Catija is right. Further details: [*Digital phobia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Phobic)

Comment: It's not exactly digital phobia because these types of people embrace the internet and use it every day. They just freak out about every kind of unknown link assuming it's a virus or something of that sort.

Comment: @EchoFive: It is not the answer itself. I just gave it because it gives more details there about this topic. It is mentioned that is a subset of technophobia in that article also.

Comment: @Catija: Would technophobia not constitute a fear of technology itself, as opposed to it being used against you by someone with malevolent intentions? This seems more related to an incessant fear of being victimized (whether burglary, robbery, or digital equivalents).

Comment: Maybe this asks for the coining of the expression kleptotechnophobia (fear of theft by electronic means) or technokleptophobia (fear of theft of electronic possessions)  :)

Comment: [This article](https://consumerjungle.org/jungle-talk/conquering-identity-theft-phobia) calls it "identity theft-phobia".

Comment: @laurisvr: That is a good one! I think it could serve as an answer if you explain how it is formed. [including the Greek origins :)]

Comment: _Techno_- isn't really the right prefix for 'electronic'; it would include safe-cracking, lock-picking, and train robbery, for instance. Why not use _elektrokleptophobia_? Fear of theft by electronic means.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It sounds more like electricity theft phobia. :). [ See: [Theft of Electricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theft_of_electricity) ]

Comment: @ermanen Thank you for the suggestion. I've supplied an answer:)

Comment: @JohnLawler That is actually better. I've taken the liberty of using your suggestions in my answer. I hope you're okay with that:)

Comment: I would call it "rational".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kindly suggested by Ermanen and John Lawler, the lack of a particular word might prompt you to coin your own -phobia in this case. Most names for a fear simply comprise the subject of the fear in Greek with phobia(greek for fear) as a suffix.

[This site](http://phobialist.com/) mentions a whole lot of them. The rule about the first word being greek [doesn't seem](http://phobialist.com/phobia_names.html) to be a very hard rule there. With it being replaced by a latin word `Hispanophobia` and `Albuminurophobia`for example take the latin words for respectively Spain (don't really know why you'd be afraid of that) and a kidney protein. To indicated fear of Spain, and fear of kidney diseases.

So I guess as long as you pick a word that sounds slighty fancy. You match the phobia criteria I reckon. My suggestions would be:

- `identitatokleptophobia` which is using Latin, but hey who cares:) I wouldn't know if there's a Greek word for identity.
- `kleptoelektrophobia` or `kleptotechnophobia` fear of theft by electronic means
- `electrokleptophobia` or `technokleptophobia` fear of theft of electronic possessions

As John Lawler has pointed out, techno as a prefix might be a bit broad. However, if you're very strictly sticking to the Greek meaning of the word. Electro actually means amber (the material). Of which our word for electricity might be derived. Which would suggest `electrokleptophobia` means you're afraid someone is intent on stealing your precious amber:).

Also of course the meaning of these words might be a bit ambiguous. However, this seems to be true for a lot of the words in the list I mentioned before.

Comment: Nice answer. +1  But *electrokleptophobia* could be ambiguous also because of "theft of electricity" :)

Comment: @ermanen True, but that's true for a lot of the phobias I think:). What word would you consider best:)?

Comment: I think "technophobia" is somewhat established already so instead of "electro" you can use "techno". "Identitatokleptophobia" seems fine but it is  clumsy. Well, we could abandon the Greek route and simply say "identity theft phobia" also. :)